# Putting django passed variables {{}} inside {% url %}

Tags: python, django

I am trying to do this

```
<form action="{% url 'add_participant' id={{event.id}} %}" method="POST">
```

But it seems that django doesn't like having a {{}} variable inside {%%}, how do I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't surround the variables in a template tag with double curly brackets. The curly double brackets are used to render variables in the template, not to pass parameters in a template tag. You thus write this as:

```
<form action="{% url 'add_participant' id=event.id %}" method="POST">
```